# What has replaced type Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerProxyDataProvider in Sitecore v9?

Tags: upgrade

I'm in the process of performing an upgrade of Sitecore 8.1 update 3 to Sitecore 9.0.1.

I have updated all the Sitecore nuget package references from 8.1 to their counterparts in 9.

When I run the site I get the following exception:

> Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerProxyDataProvider, Sitecore.Kernel (method: Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

When I decompile `Sitecore.Kernel v8.1` I can see that the type in questions exists.

When I decompile `Sitecore.Kernel v9` they type is no longer there.

Does anyone know where it has gone and / or what I should be using instead?

Comment: Where are you using SqlServerProxyDataProvider or where is it referenced from? I couldn;t find any reference in config files in OOTB instance of Sitecore 8.

Comment: I couldn't find SqlServerProxyDataProvider anywhere in the code.  I did note however that the sitecore.config had an element of proxyDataProvider whereas a fresh v9 install had dataProvider instead.  Changed the config and it got past this issue.  Looks like I will have more luck starting from a fresh v9 config and going from there.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can also accept my answer @schnitty if it helped :)

Answer (score 3):

Seems that the whole Sitecore.Data.Proxies namespace has been significantly reduced in Sitecore 9.

There is also no ProxyDisabler any more as it has been retired in this version -> https://briancaos.wordpress.com/2018/01/22/in-sitecore-9-the-proxydisabler-have-been-retired-completely/

I believe there is no replacement for Sitecore.Data.SqlServer.SqlServerProxyDataProvider or any other ProxyProviders that were there before as Proxy items are no longer supported in Sitecore 9.

Answer (score -1):

to resolve issue do action as below

From the `Sitecore.config` comment below settings for keys
both below entries came twice, so ensure to comment twice 
`proxiesEnabled`
`proxyDataProvider`

comment below tag
`proxyDataProviders`

Comment: This doesn't answer the question